# Is there a way to include a google charts panel alongside cartodb map?

Tags: carto, carto-js, chart

I have successfully included charts in infowindows (e.g. https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/infowindow_with_graph.html) but I would like to include charts in panels alongside a cartodb map. Is there a way to adjust the code in the link above to achieve this?

Comment: Thats great Andy,
Im trying to do something similar but my tables dont have numeric values, I want do draw charts on string values. For example I have a column that is divided by 3 values; inspected, not inspected and active. I would like to draw a piechart with the % of inspected, not inspected and active. Could you show me an example for doing this?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use click events to get the data from the object you click on and control where that data goes by using the callback object.

First put the `draw_chart` function from that example in the click event below:

```
sublayer.on('featureClick',function(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
    draw_chart([data.pop_min, data.pop_max], data.name);
});
```

You can then edit `draw_chart` to put the chart into whichever div element you want.

See a basic working example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ohasselblad/33e5f5f6c72f2ec45e87). It uses most of the code from the example you included.

Check out the [CartoDB.js documentation](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html) for more information.